# Is using a flat 6 in dorian to avoid an augmented fourth OK in jazz?

Tags: scales, jazz, modes

Here is a basic line of broken fourths I was playing over Dm7.

[image]

...at beat 4 I use B flat so that a fourth is formed from the preceding F. As line continues in the next bar I go back to the B natural to return to the dorian scale.

Is this traetment of the 6th of the dorian scale OK in jazz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the title of the question and the key signature, I assume the work is in D Dorian rather than C major.

If so, you're probably okay doing this, but be careful to put enough emphasis on the B natural that it sounds like the normal B note, otherwise the listener may think you are in D minor. Also, is this part of a larger piece? If so, it'll be easier to bring that dorian feel to the music. Also, why are you using the perfect fourths, if I may ask? is there a particular reason that the fourths have to be perfect? I think that usually the augmented fourth between F and B can be... **spicy**.

If you're in C major and just using the dorian mode temporarily, then that will be cool as part of a ii-V-I. In fact, I can't think of many times that it wouldn't be cool, **as long as the listener can tell you're in Dorian.**

Comment: The context would be C major, ii-V-I, with Dm7 being the ii chord. Why broken fourths? ...just a way to dress up a simple line.

Comment: Fair enough. That would sound cool in C, where th B♭is weird.

Comment: broken fourths... actually when I try that kind of line the sources I have in mind are Debussy's Arabesque and Harlem Nocturne! But I thought it could be cool in a jazz setting too. Sometimes I try starting on the off beat.

Comment: Why is it so important that the listener can tell you're in Dorian?

Comment: It would be important if the piece was written in Dorian. Truns out it isn't.

Comment: I'm asking *why* it's so important. Would non-musical listeners know? I think not.

Comment: Nonmusical listeners don't need to understand things in order to enjoy them. True, you don't have to prove you're in Dorian, but if the piece were written in Dorian, and you didn't make it sound like it, you might end up writing in D minor. I get that that isn't a bad thing, it's just that suppose one needed to be able to write in Dorian for some reason, but they can't because they end up writing in minor instead. That's the problem I was trying to guard against.

Answer (score 2):

Dorian is a 'minor mode'. There are other 'minor modes' and 'minor scales'. When a piece or a tune is in 'minor', there is rarely just the notes from one of the aforementioned.

There is no need to stick to one set of notes (a scale), when playing. in fact, it often sound better - particularly in jazz playing - to spice things up with an 'odd' note or two.

In this situation, which looking at the key sig., could be D Dorian, yes, the 'go to' note would be Bnat. rather than Bb. However, why does the listener *need to know* that the piece *is* in D Dorian, even if it adheres strictly to 'the rules'. Which, as we well know, music doesn't...

As ever, whichever you, as the player, regards as better choice, is the one to go for.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's OK.  And the B nat would be OK too.  Maybe you'd want to apply a different label to 'dorian' to that bit.   So what?